# Насколько целесообразно использовать хранения данный на двух сайтах

Tags: безопасность

Насколько целесообразно использовать хранения данный на двух сайтах указана в блок схеме

Моя логика такая, которую я указал в блок схеме.

1. Есть сайт 1 , в него пользователь вносит данные.
2. Сайт 2 проверяет является ли ip + домен с которого приходит запрос доверенным и шифрует или расшифровывает данные и отправляет обратно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Насколько имеет место быть данная логика и насколько это становится безопаснее или наоброт нет. Как действовать правильно, что бы как можно сильнее обезопасить и зашифровать данные сайта. Так как правило воруют базы данных сайта, но если там всё зашифровано, то в целом данная бд безсмыслена.

Comment: Ну взломают сайт1 и через него сольют все расшифрованные данные. Или взломают сайт2 и украдут пароли/ключи для расшифровки и расшифруют бд

Comment: Ну в этом случае недоброжелателям, нужно будет взломать 2 сайта. А это ещё сложнее, мне кажется, поэтому и выбираю такую логику.

Comment: В обоих случаях достаточно взломать один сайт (иу или я из вашей схемы не понял, почему нужно взламывать именно два)

Comment: Если вы взломаете сайт1 и скачаете бд  где хранятся данные в зашифрованном виде , то вы не сможете понять их, так как расшифровка происходит только на сайте 2, но данные сайт2 не хранит он только расшифровывает данные в сайте 1 и отправляет обратно расшифрованные данные или шифрует их.

Comment: «и отправляет обратно расшифрованные данные» — вот именно на этом моменте злоумышленник, взломавший сайт1, и сможет украсть расшифрованные данные. Взламывать сайт2 для этого не требуется, скачивать зашифрованную бд тоже нет необходимости, сайт2 сам добровольно пришлёт злоумышленнику расшифрованные данные